# Solr highlight returned for one document only

Tags: solr, highlight

Solr Vserion 4.7
When i query solr with hl=true, it returns highlight info for only last document in the results. Not for all.

query:
&hl=true

```
` response: {
  numFound: 20,
  start: 0,
  docs: [
       {
          id: 23344936
       },
       {
          id: 20863812
       },
       {
          id: 23997056
       },
       {
          id: 22994827
       },
       { 
          id: 22924444
       }
    ]
 },
highlighting: {
       : {
        text: [
              ", matlab, matlab, matlab, matlab, matlab, matlab,  matlab, matlab, matlab, matlab, matlab, <em>python</em>, <em>python</em>"
              ]
        }
 }`
```

Comment: You should explain your problem more and also what you have tried. Most of the time you need to add your code to let people understand your problem and be able to help you.

Comment: have you created all the documents at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys i figured out the issue.
It was with json plugin i was using which was rendering only one doc as key's were not present in the response dict.
What key's were not present?
We have not "stored=true" our "uniqueKey" in schema.xml.